# how to show objects (List<>) on datadgridview and make edit, delete?

Tags: c#, datagridview, entity

i have working in the business layer on my app and i want to show a objects list<>.
Thanks.

the app are in C#.

```
//view layer
dataGridView1.DataSource = RecMatBLL.Inventary.GetTODOInventory(); //dont show but compile

//business layer
public static List<Inventory> GetTODOInventory() {
        List<Inventory> newInventory = new List<Inventory>();
        List<InventoryEntity> inventorys = Provider.Inventory.GetInventory();
        foreach (InventoryEntity i in inventorys)
        {
            newInventory.Add(new Inventory(i.IdComponent, i.IdLot, i.Volume, i.Description, i.Location));
        }
        return newInventory;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are elements in the list and not it is empty?

Comment: how is your datagridview  set up? are columns custom or are they auto-generated?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. The list is not empty.

Comment: the datagridview it's auto-generated